# С# WSAEINVAL (10022) Invalid argument on socket create

Tags: c#, windows-7, winsock, winsock2

I'm trying to create a chat on C# with WinSock (System.Net.Sockets) for the institute. On my computer everything works fine. On the ones in the institute it throws an exception on the line:

> socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

SocketException: WSAEINVAL (10022) Invalid argument on socket create.
All arguments are absolutely following the guidelines.

I managed to find [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/3076a9cd-57a0-418d-8de1-07adc3b486bb/socket-fails-with-error-10022-when-application-is-run-from-certain-network-shares-on-vista-and?forum=wsk) thread (seems like my kind of problem).

Microsoft even created a [patch](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/2649107/winsock-based-operations-fail-in-windows-7-or-in-windows-server-2008-r) to this one.

Institute computer runs on Windows7. I got no administator rights neither I am allowed to show chat on my notebook. So, it seems that I cannot edit windows registry or install an update. Are there any ways for me to fix or avoid this problem?

Comment: Are you running your EXE from a network share, like [this discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/3076a9cd-57a0-418d-8de1-07adc3b486bb/socket-fails-with-error-10022-when-application-is-run-from-certain-network-shares-on-vista-and?forum=wsk) described? If not, then I can't see `new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)` producing a `WSAEINVAL` error unless IPv4 is not installed on the machine, making the `AddressFamily.InterNetwork` (`AF_INET`) address family unavailable. Use `WSAEnumProtocols()` to verify that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau how would you solve the issue if it was running from a networkshare ?